# How to remove side space

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm working on this website http://shapeofyou.lotusong.info/ and I am trying to make the boxes on the main page fill up the entire screen. How do I do that? I tried looking for any padding or margin but there wasn't any. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: please show your relevant  code NOT link (also show what you tried so far)

Comment: Are you using a page builder? Surely it has an option for full-width on it..

Comment: My wordpress theme doesnt not include a option for full-width

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.container` and `.wppb-container` have a `max-width` applied.  Set them both to 100% and you'll be good.

Comment: I will try this thank you